# Macro doesnt appear on the List after copy-pasting code

Tags: vba, excel

I am completely new to VBA and hence have no idea what I'm doing...
Below is the description of my problem and also the code in question.

What I originally wanted to do was this:
Copy a clicked cell, Select new sheet, Select any cell, Paste as values

Now i found a code that apparently does the trick which is this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("A")) Is Nothing Then
     Cancel = True
     If Target.Row > 1 And Len(Target.Value) Then Worksheets("S11").Range("C2").Value = Target.Value
  End If
End Sub
```

I say "apparently" as I am not able to test it. Here is the problem:

1. I saved the workbook as excel macro-enabled workbook
2. Clicked ALT Q - to go back to my workbook
3. I then ALT F8 to run it - but there is nothing there... blank....

what am I missing?

Comment: Alt-F8 will only display macros that can be run.  The `worksheet_change` event is `Private` and therefore not publicly accessible, and it also requires a parameter to be passed to it which you can't do unless it is called by something else.  You can check to see if it exists again by looking in the code window for the sheet you placed it in.  But it should run whenever you put a non-blank value into column A (except for in cell A1).

Comment: Your macro above is designed to be placed in the worksheet object, and will run if the cell selected on that sheet changes. Also, it appears to only do anything if the newly active cell is in column A. It sets `Cancel` to `True` which is not going to do anything in that `Event` (I think). If it is in column A, it then checks that it's not on `Row` 1, and it isn't blank. If so, it copies the value stored in the newly active cell so `S11!C2`. Is that actually what you want?

Comment: Thank you all so much... it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a module, have the macro you wish to use.

```
public sub mymacro(r as excel.range)
If Not Intersect(r, Columns("A")) Is Nothing Then         
     If r.Row > 1 And Len(r.Value) Then Worksheets("S11").Range("C2").Value= r.Value
  End If
end sub

public sub wbtest()
    mymacro activecell
end sub
```

and use like so

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("A")) Is Nothing then
        mymacro target
    end if
end sub
```